# Append querystring to view render function Django

Tags: python, django, django-views

I got `querystring` in my view:

```
def my_view(request):
    query_string  = request.GET
```

Then I do some staff in this view. Finally I want to append `querystring` to URL of view when page rendered completely:

```
return render(request, 'my_template.html', context=context) # Want to add querystring here!
```

**In brief I want to append `querystring` to view render function or something like that. How can I do that?**

---

**Rendering Process:**

I think that I must declare my purpose. I will explain all rendering process and I define what I mean. See:

1. User click on link that come to this view(Send request). Suppose that this is our link:

   ```py
   site.com/my/page/?q1=value_1&q2=value_2
   ```
2. View function call:

   ```py
   # urls.py
   path('my/page/', my_view)

   # views.py
   def my_view(request):
       query_string  = request.GET
   ```
3. Render template with `request`, `template` and `context`:

   ```py
   return render(request, 'my_template.html', context=context)
   ```
4. After complete html and all static files, we have html page that has `URL` and `html`.

I want to add my primary `querystring` to URL of process 4. How can I do that?

Comment: The querystring is already at the end of the URL when you render that specific view. Note that the name of the *template* has nothing to do with the URL. Each view can render zero, one or more templates, and each template can be rendered in zero, one or more views.

Comment: Hi Willem. Please see my new edit @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: but normally the URL will remain `site.com/my/page/?q1=value_1&q2=value_2`, not `site.com/my_template.html`, since a template has no impact on the paths.

Comment: I know that template dosen't has impact on the path! I mean: when my view rendered, I got this: `site.com/my/page/`, and I want to got this: `site.com/my/page/?q1=value_1&q2=value_2` @WillemVanOnsem

Comment: but where does the `?q1=...` originates from? `request.GET` specifies the querystring *at that moment*. So if you visit it with `site.com/my/page`, then there is no querysetring, and `request.GET` will thus be empty.

Comment: I did generate that with `JQuery` in my template. @WillemVanOnsem